# Combining relational operators with grep -q in shell IF statement?

Tags: shell-script, shell

I can't find an answer for this - apologies if it's a duplicate.

I'm using `/bin/sh` on BSD (**not** bash!) and I'm trying to figure out the syntax for the following IF statement.

I have two component clauses. Written as separate statements it looks like this:

```
if [ "$a" == "y" -o "$a" == "Y" ]; then
    if printf '%s' "$b" | grep -qE 'SOME_REGEX'; then
        # both conditions met: do stuff
    fi
fi
```

So I can use nested `if` as a workaround.

But what syntax do I need, to combine them neatly into a single "if" statement?

*NOTE: If this shell allows direct regex match comparisons (`[ "$a" =~ REGEX" ]` or similar) instead of requiring `grep -q`, that would be useful to know, but I'd still like to know how to correctly combine these clauses as they stand, because some day I will surely have a situation where I'm matching file contents and the second statement is something like `ls -l "$b" | grep -qE 'SOME_REGEX'` instead, so an inline regex comparison wouldn't work... :)*

Comment: Is the `grep` regex complicated enough that a glob is insufficient?

Comment: Yes. Not _that_ complex, but enough so, that globbing won't cut it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally think it's ok to have a nested `if` statement here, although I would have used slightly modernized syntax:

```
if [ "$a" = "y" ] || [ "$a" = "Y" ]; then
    if printf '%s' "$b" | grep -qE 'SOME_REGEX'; then
        # both conditions met: do stuff
    fi
fi
```

(note that `==` is a `bash`-ism)

To combine them (makes it less readable IMHO):

```
if [ "$a" = "y" ] || [ "$a" = "Y" ] && printf '%s' "$b" | grep -qE 'SOME_REGEX'; then
    # both conditions met: do stuff
fi
```

For *basic* regular expressions, you can use `expr` (see [comment by  Stéphane Chazelas below though](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas)):

```
if [ "$a" = "y" ] || [ "$a" = "Y" ] && expr "$b" : 'SOME_REGEX' >/dev/null; then
    # both conditions met: do stuff
fi
```

The `/bin/sh` shell does not generally have `[[ ... =~ ... ]]` to do extended regular expression matching.

---

Regarding your note at the end: Regular expressions are for matching across single lines of *text*.  If you treat filenames as text, you automatically disqualify any filename that is not a single line of text, such as filenames containing newlines.  If you need to apply regular expression matching to filenames, do so carefully with the names stored in an array (`$@` in `/bin/sh`), or use an implementation of  `find` that supports the `-regex` predicate.

Filename globbing patterns are for matching filenames.

Comment: `(...)` starts a subshell which in most shells involve forking an extra process. It would make more sense to use a command group (`{...;}`), though in this particular case `[ "$a" = y ] || [ "$a" = Y ] && grep ...` would work just as well.

Comment: `expr` can't be used like that for arbitrary data as it would fail for values of `$b` that are expr operators. Also note that regexps in expr are anchored at the start  (not end). You can use a leading space like `expr " $b" : " regexp"`

Answer (score 1):

Note that `grep` matches each line of the input, not the input as a whole, so is generally not suitable for arbitrary strings. You can use `awk` instead for that (beware that's *extended regular expressions* similar to those understood by `grep -E` or `bash`'s `[[ string =~ regexp ]]`).

```
regexp_match() {
  awk 'BEGIN{if (ARGV[1] !~ ARGV[2]) exit(1)}' "$@"
}

if [ "$a" = y ] || [ "$a" = Y ] && regexp_match "$b" REGEXP; then
   ...
fi
```

Note that the `-a`/`-o` `[` binary operators should be avoided. They're deprecated by POSIX, and have a number of issues. For instance, here on FreeBSD:

```
$ a='(' /bin/sh -c '[ "$a" = y -o "$a" = Y ]'
[: closing paren expected
```

Answer (score 0):

You could shorten it by making `$a` concatenated with `$b` and add pattern to regex

```
 if printf '%s%s\n' "$a" "$b" | grep -qE '^[yY]SOME_REGEX'; then
```

Note that grep is line matching tool, hence \n at the end

Comment: That could however give false positives (like with `a='' b=ySOME_REGEX` or `a=ySOM`, `b=E_REGEXP`).

Comment: @Stephane Could that be improved with adding a separator perhaps or grouping  ?

Comment: Possibly with something like `expr "${#a}$a$b" : '1[yY]SOME_REGEX' > /dev/null`

Comment: Sneaky! But less easy for someone else to check, to be sure it's correct code, in a collaborative project. But would definitely work. The issues of a blank or unset string can be solved using `"${a:-UNSET} $b"` or some such, it's not a hard workaround. If $a could contain spaces if misentered and all we care about is yes/no, then `tr ' ' '_'` or similar would fix it, or a bit of checking first, or a better regex.